# Residues of $a^n+b^n$ modulo $n^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Recently I’ve found a problem: if $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ prove that $a^n+b^n\equiv m \bmod n^2$ has solutions for no more than $n^2/2$ different residues $m$.

I’ve figured out that if $x \equiv y \bmod n$, $x^n \equiv y^n \bmod n^2$, and therefore $a^n$ gives no more than $n$ residues mod $n^2$, but I don’t know what to do next. Any thoughts?

Comment: Given $m,n,$ a solution $(a,b)$ gives another solution $(b,a),$ unless $a\equiv b\pmod n.$ So this gives $\frac{n(n-1)}2+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$ possible different values $m.$ That's a little more than you want, but it is a start.

Comment: This is false for $n=1,2,3$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Moreover, if $n$ is odd then $-1$ is an $n$-th power and so you get $n$ ordered pairs that sum to $0$. So this gives at most $\tfrac{n^2+1}{2}$ different values.